# Matplotlib surface_plot colormap getting poisoned by Nan's?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 3d matplotlib surfaceplot.  the Z axis is standard deviation (betwen -4,+4).  I made a color map to make -4 = red, 0 white, and +4 green.

```
cmap1 = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("my_colormap", ((1, 0, 0),(1,.25,.25),(1,1,1), (0.25,1,0.25),(0, 1, 0)), N=15, gamma=1.0)
```

It has worked fine.  But now I removed half the redundant values of the data but converting the lower triangular matrix to NaN (and also the (1,1) (2,2)...(n,n) points = Nan).

This reveals an artifact I dislike.  The polygons the surface plot draws at the border of the region with data and the region with Nans gives bright red polygons that defy the colormap of the chart. I have attached a picture of what I mean,  in both both cases it's an ugly and confusing artifact [image: I have attached a picture of what I mean, in both both cases it's an ugly and confusing artifact].

Does anyone know how I can eliminate this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a serious work around, and likely not the most helpful. But it is possible to transform your domain so that your valid values take up a the full array. Think of it as "stretching your data". This results in a solid line being plotted.

It involves crafting your x and y inputs, and then using scipy's interp2d to find the corresponding z value.

A nasty workaround I know, but it is the best I could come up with in a pinch in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was instead of putting NaN's along the (0,0), (1,1)..(n,n), I made those zeros. The rest I still changed to Nans.  This eliminates the ugly red tear.

instead of  `raw[np.tril_indices(raw.shape[0],-1)] = np.nan`

I used `raw[np.tril_indices(raw.shape[0],0)] = np.nan`

[image]

Comment: An alternative would be to mask the values rather than set them to NaN